# Caching js lib and html content in webview with React native

Tags: caching, react-native

I wrote an app with react native, but it is hard for me to draw charts in the app.

I used a `WebView` to show the charts view but I found it is slow to load that way.

Is there any way to cache the js lib and `WebView` context locally so that when the app starts it doesn't need to load the js and html content from server?

Comment: Hi there. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I am also very interested to this, we need caching for the webview, do we have any more info on this?